# SharePoint Information Management Policy settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, information-policy, information-lifecycle-management

This is about SharePoint 2013 on premises environment.

The requirement is to send annual reminder to approvers to review the documents in a library. I set up the information management policy to created + 10 months(reminder 2 month before its due)  and the action as start the workflow. I check the reoccurrence box to repeat this every year. Everything works until this point.

Now the user wants another reminder to send out a month prior its due along with the 2 months reminder.

My question is, If I add another stage to set the reminder to a month and enable reoccurrence, will the 2 months reminders get triggered for the second year? Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: are you enable recurrence for each stage ? what I the recurrence period value you have set ?

Comment: Since the reminders should go out every year, I have added recurrence for both the stages. But I am confused by the sentence which is in the recurrence section of retention policy window which is "Repeat this stage action until the next stage is triggered". Is that means the 2 months reminder will not trigger for second year as it will be in second stage?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest testing it in a test environment.  Try setting the reminders (i.e. the recurrence) to be generated after +1 day and after +2 days - this way you are testing the concept of having the two sets of reminders being generated.  As you suggested, you would need to have two retention stages for this purpose.

In order to do the above testing you will need to adjust timer jobs on the server; by default they only run every week.  Change this to daily in order for the testing to work correctly.  Here is a [post on a Microsoft Technet website](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0989ed09-5495-4e59-b99d-2605ef0c14a2/information-management-policy-retention-not-working?forum=sharepointgeneral) that gives instructions on changing the frequency of the timer jobs.

I believe I am correct in saying the recurrence will keep going.  So if the user reviewing the task (sounds like you are using a document disposition task?) keeps selecting 'do not delete' the document, the recurrence will keep restarting and make a new task to review the document.  Only once the document is deleted will the recurrence cycle end and no more tasks will be made!

I hope this helps a little.

Regards,

David